# FormData key as array

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

I am trying to setup a multiple file upload, using FormData html5 api.
The problem  is that i cannot delete index of an array that is on FormData key.
ex:

```
if(editor.frmData){
        editor.frmData.append( 'upload[]', files[0] );
    }else{
        editor['frmData']=new FormData();
    }
```

This is the code i execute when i select a file. I select more than one file and on the server (php) , $_FILES is array with arrays.
ex:

```
    Array
(
    [upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Screenshot from 2017-02-21 16:04:36.png
                    [1] => 20170314_124241.jpg
                    [2] => mob geografica.png
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/png
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpVQEmFd
                    [1] => /tmp/phpE5xKUf
                    [2] => /tmp/php0f4cbi
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1088612
                    [1] => 1324555
                    [2] => 410839
                )
        ))
```

My question is how can i delete an entry in formData ex:

```
editor.frmData.delete('upload[1]');
```

or

```
editor.frmData.delete('upload["name"][1]');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function to delete one of many values for the same name:

```
function formDataDelete(frmData, name, index) {
    var keep = frmData.getAll(name);
    keep.splice(index, 1);
    frmData.delete(name);
    keep.forEach( value => frmData.append(name, value) );
}
```

It just deletes the name (and thus all values associated with it), and adds all values again, except the one that was at the indicated index.

Comment: Sorry downvote trincot . This is a magnificent solution

Comment: How can i rename name['name'][index]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? You want to rename `upload[]` to `something_else` for a given index, so it is no longer part of the "array" of values for `upload[]`? NB: new questions should better be posted as such.

Comment: In question , i have on server the upload[] and upload['name' ,' type' ...] . upload['name'] is also an array. As I need to rename the files i need to change upload['name'][index]

Comment: So you want `$_FILES["upload"]["name"][0] = "somenewfilename";`?

Comment: exatly my friend

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There is [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) to set a key, and also [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) which will do the same thing without overwriting the existing key with the same name.

But set has its opposite in [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete), append doesn't have an opposite.

The only way to do it is to delete the key and then rewrite all the values you want to keep to it.